# excel one column with many word duplicates and the other with values (number) and need to sum all values for each word with formula

Tags: excel, formulas

excel. 
One column with US states (many duplicates) and the other with values (number) and need to sum all values for each state with formula, how do I make a formula that recognize when words are the same without telling the word in formula.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to do a pivot table.

1. Select your Data
2. Insert --> PivotTable and select new worksheet
3. Add your US States in the Row label
4. Add the Value column in the Value Tab

Now you can click on your Value Tab and mark the Sum to sum up all values per State